# Ext JS Layout Error

Tags: javascript, html, css, extjs

i have some problems with my Layout. I have serveral `Ext.form.Panel` with further items, for example `textfields`. When the item (xtype) is empty, no error occurred. But when i fill the item with text, the content of it displace itself.

Example:

(This is, when i write a text without leaving the field)

[image]

(This is, when i leaving the field, for example to step into another field)

[image]

The error also occurred for example in a `combobox`

The next problem is, that the bottom border of the fields cut off, for example:

[image]

Here is the complete form (The error occurred in every form)

[image]

Info: The forms are built with the sencha Architect

Thanks

Comment: What browser are you testing it in? Is it happening in other browsers too?

Comment: https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?301227-Visual-combobox-bug-in-Chrome-43.0.2357.65-m/page2&s=869a1bff90028d5aff9ba4d79d4e893e

Comment: Hmpf ... embarrassing! In Firefox it works, but in Crome not...
Normally I use Crome.

But why it doesn't work in crome?

Comment: Was this question not answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The forum post suggests that you set the form text class with display: block;
I would rather set display: inherit; to avoid further issues.

Just add this css to your project:

```
.x-form-text {
    display: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in chrome currently. Take a look here for the workaround:

https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?301227-Visual-combobox-bug-in-Chrome-43.0.2357.65-m&p=1101244&viewfull=1#post1101244